# html js project on live preview keeps on refreshing when submit button is clicked as a result desired page flashes in few seconds

Tags: javascript, html

i am doing a project in which if a person enters his date of birth it will show when he was born, how much seconds he have born like that few features.
i am having trouble while running the first part.
on the first part when the user enters the dob and click submit it shows the result and immediately refreshes to the initial state
the project can be seen here https://boring-euclid-39980f.netlify.com/

the program is done using html and javascript

```
var mysubmit = document.getElementById("mysubmit");
mysubmit.onclick = function(){

   var mydate = document.getElementById("date").value;
   if(mydate === ""){
      alert("ENTER YOUR DATE OF BIRTH");}
      else{
         var birthday = new Date(mydate);
         var year = birthday.getFullYear();
         var birthdate = birthday.getDate();
         document.getElementById("yr").innerHTML = year;
         document.getElementById("no").innerHTML = birthdate;


      }

}
```

```
<body>
    <div id="formcontainer">
        <form id="myForm">
            ENTER YOUR DOB : <input type="date" id="date"><br>
            <button id="mysubmit">SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="answer">
        YOU ARE BORN ON <span id="no">.</span> OF <span id="mo">.</span> IN <span id="yr">.</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you put a button in a form it will submit your form data which means your page will be refreshed. Generally, you only need this functionality if you're sending your form data to your server. However, in your case, you don't need to send your form data to the server and instead just need to retrieve your data from the javascript client code.

Thus, in order to stop your page from refreshing you can give your button a `type` of `button`, such that you tell your from not to submit the data when the button is pressed:

```
<button type="button" id="mysubmit">SUBMIT</button>
```

See example below:

```js
var mysubmit = document.getElementById("mysubmit");
mysubmit.onclick = function() {
  var mydate = document.getElementById("date").value;
  if (mydate === "") {
    alert("ENTER YOUR DATE OF BIRTH");
  } else {
    var birthday = new Date(mydate);
    var year = birthday.getFullYear();
    var birthdate = birthday.getDate();
    document.getElementById("yr").innerHTML = year;
    document.getElementById("no").innerHTML = birthdate;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="formcontainer">
    <form id="myForm">
      ENTER YOUR DOB : <input type="date" id="date"><br>
      <button type="button" id="mysubmit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="answer">
    YOU ARE BORN ON <span id="no">.</span> OF <span id="mo">.</span> IN <span id="yr">.</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you need to submit the data to your server and display your results, you can submit your form and get the data returned by the server and display that once the page has refreshed. Alternatively, you could do POST request to your server if you need to pass your data from your form to your server without refreshing the page. To do the POST request you could look into using the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or do an [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call with the help of [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 1):

As a default state, the submit button will refresh the page when you click on it, **unless you mention otherwise**, for doing so, we have three methodes:

1. You can `return false` when the submit button is clicked using javascript events:
   `<button id="mysubmit" onclick="return false">SUBMIT</button>`
2. You can prevent the default state of the submit button by mentioning it in you javascript file:

```
mysubmit.onclick = function(event){

   event.preventDefault()

   var mydate = document.getElementById("date").value;
   if(mydate === ""){
      alert("ENTER YOUR DATE OF BIRTH");}
      else{
         var birthday = new Date(mydate);
         var year = birthday.getFullYear();
         var birthdate = birthday.getDate();
         document.getElementById("yr").innerHTML = year;
         document.getElementById("no").innerHTML = birthdate;


      }

}
```

3. As mentiond in a different answer to this question when you put a submit button inside a `<form>` it will by default, refresh you page, therefore you need to specify the the type of your button is `type="button"` otherwise, your website will think it is a submit button and it will refresh your page:
   `<button id="mysubmit" type="button">SUBMIT</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Change the button type="submit" to type="button"

`<button type="button" id="myButton">SUBMIT</button>`

or in the click event

`event.preventDefault(); // it will stop the default form submit behavior.`